# Is there any way to see kill/death ratio per weapon, map, or kit?

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

Subject says it all. I really wish I had those more finely grained statistics but since it's not on the battle log site, I'm guessing it's simply not available (unless I've missed it somewhere).

Comment: you can try an alternative stats site like http://bf3stats.com

Comment: Bf3stats.com has some more stats, which is good, but not these. I'm not sure how they get their data (screen scraping?) so I'm guess it's not possible :(

Comment: They get their data by EA providing the APIs so external sites can pull the stats directly from the game. This has existed since at least Bad Company 2, maybe earlier. There are a multitude of sites out there, google "Battlefield 3 stats" and try to look at other ones, but it may not be possible. External sites did have these stats for Bad Company 2, but I haven't seen them for Battlefield 3 yet.

Comment: Do you know where EA publishes the API? I've actually looked for it since that was my first inclination but it doesn't seem it's terribly public. I wouldn't mind writing my own little program but I can't find any API documentation from EA. BF3stats has API doc, but that seems to be just for their stuff.

Comment: I do not. You might have to contact them (EA) to get that info, or they may only give it to certain places. If you find it, post back with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think one exists.

http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/7613964.page

Also, it seems previous BF games did not have a public API. It was just sites using existing sources to get the information, much as it seems a site like BF3Stats is doing.